# ImportError: dlopen when running pyside6 app | Python

Tags: python, macos, pyside6

I am trying to run my app on mac, I got my whole code to an IMac;then, I installed all my libraries, but when I run it, it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/Desktop/~/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/QtWidgets.abi3.so, 2): Symbol not found: _NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Desktop/~/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/A/QtCore
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Users/user/Desktop/~/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/A/QtCore
```

I searched it, but no luck. I am running on Python 3.10 and PySide 6.3, Can anyone help me?

Comment: And *OSX* version, *CPU* architecture?

Comment: OS 10.12.6 Sierra | 2.7 GHz intel core i5

Comment: How can the OS version and CPU architecture affect it @CristiFati

Comment: `_NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua` is only available on MacOS 10.14 (Mojave) or newer. It's dark mode so if you're trying to use dark mode in your app, it will fail on your 10.12.x Mac.

Comment: No I am not using darkmode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[Apple.Developer]: NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancenamedarkaqua?language=objc) (**emphasis** is mine):

> macOS 10.**14+**

So, this package is not compatible (too new) with your *OS* version. Either:

- Upgrade *OSX* to *Mojave* (or later). **This would be the recommended way**
- Use an older *PySide6* package - try the oldest ([[PyPI]: PySide6 6.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/PySide6/6.0.0/): `pip install PySide6==6.0.0`), but I doubt it would solve your issue as it's still too new (and it was probably built against libraries that export *NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua*)

  - Switch to a replacement package like [[PyPI]: PySide2](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2) (I think that one uses *Qt**5*** under the hood)
  - Try building *PySide6* (and most likely *Qt6*) locally, but that will be quite a painful process (even for an experienced developer)

Comment: I tried Pyside2 and it worked, also thanks for the other note about updating MacOS version

Comment: That's cool!!! :)